# How to get a global variable in a function while the latter has a homonymic local variable?

Tags: python

```
a = 1
def b():
    for c in range(10):
        if c % 2 == 0:
            a = c
        else:
            a = a
    print(a)
b()
```

I want to "assgin global.a to b.a", but `a = a` does not work while it just assign the local `a` to local `a`. So how to access the global `a` and assign it to the `a` in `b`?

Do not change the name of `a` in `b`.

Comment: You can't do this. I can't even begin to imagine why you would want to.

Comment: See this code: https://gist.github.com/acgtyrant/ac3ed25b54186ad984c97a1200e49eee @DanielRoseman

Comment: That gist doesn't show any good reason for wanting to keep the same name as the global function. Why not just call the reference `removal_func` or something like that?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I forget to note that there is a loop statement in `main` actually, so `remove_unvalid_line` in `main` always change; If I do not keep the same name as the global function, I can not drop out a good alternative name...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `globals()`. Though I do not recommend any of this, it can be done. Also, **I can't even begin to imagine why you would want to** as Daniel commented.

```
def b():
    for c in range(10):
        if c % 2 == 0:
            a = c
        else:
            a = globals()['a']
        print a
```